# How to enforce constructor in Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Is there any way to enforce a specific constructor in Java classes?

For example I want all classes that inherit from a Class to have a constructor like -

```
public classname(string s1,string s2){....}
```

I know it should not be avoided because it can lead to problems with multiple inheritance. But is there a way to do it anyway?

Comment: Simply: no. Sorry.

Comment: "_I know it should not be done_" They why do it? Why on earth would you practice doing things the wrong way?

Comment: Constructors cannot be overridden. It is to create instance of class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you force constructor signatures and static methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161231/how-do-you-force-constructor-signatures-and-static-methods)

Comment: _"I know it should not be avoided because it can lead to problems with multiple inheritance."_ Well, java doesn't support multiple inheritance.

Comment: @BackSlash Not exactly. It supports multiple inheritance of contract, not of implementation.

Comment: @ju ho: why do you need it?

Comment: if you have a custom constructor and no no-arg constructor in your super class your subclasses must implement at least a super() call to it as the implicit super() call would lead to a compiler error. Its really no good practise though.

Comment: I need it because I load classes at runtime with the reflection API and I want all the classes I load to have a specific constructor. All the classes I load inherit from another class so i was wondering if I can just enforce it.

Comment: @juho all you can do here is to check presence of constructor with required signature when loading these classes.

Comment: @juho Ok, got it. Maybe the factory design pattern can be helpful for you? This may help getting rid of the reflection API too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no facilities in Java to do that directly.

However, it can be enforced to some extent usin an `abstract` method.

```
abstract class Base {

    Base(String s1, String s2) {
        init(s1, s2);
    }

    protected abstract void init(String s1, String s2);
}

class MyClass extends Base {

    // Forced to do this.
    MyClass() {
        super("One", "Two");
    }

    // Forced to do this.
    @Override
    protected void init(String s1, String s2) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want that there is only one constructor, and that with the same signature.
That could in a costly way done with reflection, at run-time.

```
public BaseClass(String s, String t, int n) {
    Class<?> cl = getClass();
    do {
        check(cl);
        cl = cl.getSuperclass();
    } while (cl != BaseClass.class);
}

private void check(Class<?> cl) {
    if (cl.getConstructors().length != 1) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Needs only 1 constructor in: " + cl.getName());
    }
    try {
        cl.getConstructor(String.class, String.class, int.class);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Constructor should have parameter types (String, String, int) in: " + cl.getName());
    }
}
```

***Not advisable***

However you could make a factory to be used that hides class hierarchies. Or in fact use a single class that delegates to your class hierarchy (has a member of your class).

Comment: If classes are loaded once, cost is negligible

Comment: @SashaSalauyou you are right, however the check must be done in non-static code, here the constructor. However one could make a `static Set<Class<? extends BaseClass>>` of already checked classes.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but no, you cannot force classes to *only* implement a specific constructor.

Comment: Yes you can. Make an abstract class with a protected constructor. Everything which is an implementation of that class must call the  constructor

Comment: @Mark must call, but must not have the same constructor.

Comment: Oops -- I missed an operative word "... to *only* implement..." in my response response. Thanks for catching that. :)

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I get what he's saying. We're probably debating semantics of my poorly worded answer Yes, you must define an explicit constructor, at least by calling super(...) in the child class

Comment: That's what I meant. With the abstract method you must define a constructor but indeed your implementing class could implement its own however it likes.